# know how the admin or the restaurant owner knows the orders, I mean in web you can login as admin and see orders from admin panel but in mobile

Tags: ios, admin

I am beginner in objective c, I am working on an n application that enables the user to detain in a restaurant with name, mobile number, number of people and time.
there is no login ...I just want to know how the admin or the restaurant owner knows the orders, I mean in web you can login as admin and see orders from admin panel but in mobile...I cannot get it.
can anyone helps me plz?

any suggestions for my app??
thanks a lot

Comment: This is a very broad question, try to ask one specific question at the time, see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It may be board but I need to understand :) @Koen

Comment: That's not how SO works.

Comment: Your app should be no different from a web application; it's just a different UI (app versus web UI). The user enters the information and the app sends the information to a central server. The `admin` person can login to the app (or via a web interface) and view the central server/database information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this You must call "API". Which give you information about the user is customer or admin.